# Checking if a table exists and if it does not exist, create it... iOS/SQLite

Tags: ios, sqlite

I currently have a table that exists which I'm able to pull data from.  What I would like to do is check if the table already exists in the bundle, and if it does not, I want to create the table and save it to the bundle (meaning the path would be in the main bundle).  I want the database to be checked and created at the top of the setInput method.  I've been scouring SO for something similar to this, but I haven't come up with anything yet.  Any help is very appreciated.  Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)setInput:(id)sender
{
    NSString *strStoreNumber;
    NSString *strRegNumber;

    strStoreNumber = StoreNumber.text;
    strRegNumber = RegNumber.text;
    lblStoreNumber.text = strStoreNumber;
    lblRegNumber.text = strRegNumber;

    NSString* databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tblStore" ofType:@"sqlite"];

    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Opened sqlite database at %@", databasePath);
        sqlite3_exec(database, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblStore (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Message TEXT)", NULL, NULL, NULL);
        //...stuff
    } 
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to open database at %@ with error %s", databasePath, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        sqlite3_close (database);
    }
//    
    NSString *querystring;

    // create your statement
    querystring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT strStore, strReg FROM tblStore WHERE strStore = %@ AND strReg = %@;", strStoreNumber, strRegNumber];  

    const char *sql = [querystring UTF8String];

    NSString *szStore = nil;
    NSString *szReg = nil;

    sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL)!=SQLITE_OK) //queryString = Statement
    {
        NSLog(@"sql problem occured with: %s", sql);
        NSLog(@"%s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    else
    {
        // you could handle multiple rows here
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
        {            
            szStore = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            szReg = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
        }        

    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    lblStoreNumber.text = szStore;
    lblRegNumber.text = szReg;

//   
}
```

I'm still quite new to iOS and SQLite, so if I did not provide an accurate enough description of what I'm trying to do, let me know and I'll try to be more specific.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick search for "iphone sql create table if not exists" gave [this](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-sqlite-on-the-iphone) as the top result.

This part of the SQL is probably what you are looking for:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableName( ... )
```

It creates a table if it does not already exist.

Comment: I edited my code under the sqlite3_open method and added similar logic for table creation.  I deleted my existing table out of my project (through Finder) and when I try to run the app, I get an error:  "error: /Users/Matt****/Documents/iOS Projects/CCoDBTry/CCoDBTry/tblStore.sqlite: No such file or directory".  Could you offer a little more insight on this?

Comment: I guess I'm also not following how to make it not exist.  I thought removing it from the project location in Finder would do the trick, but I can't even compile when I do that.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Seems like you deleted not only the table, but the whole database. You could try to recover the database-file you deleted in Finder, and then try again. If you want to delete only that particular table, you can use `DROP TABLE tableName`. Also, check out [this blog](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/#init-db).

Answer (score 0):

Create table using sqlite swift

```
func createTable(_ tableName:String) {
        sqlStatement = "CREATE TABLE \(tableName)(Id TEXT,Details BLOB,Type TEXT)"
        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement,-1, &compiledStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
            if sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_DONE {
                print("table created")
            }
            else {
                print("table could not be created")
            }
        }
        else {
            print("Create table statement could not be prepared")
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement)
    }
```